# access nested object's keys using variable object name

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, drop-down-menu

Not 100% sure my question's title accurately states my question, I apologize in advance. Please correct me if my terminology is off here.

Basically, I have a select box. When the user makes a selection I want to create a new select box setting its options using the values stored in an object:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rk7j9/) **showing my attempt**

**My Code:**

**HTML :**

```
<SELECT id="mainIssueType"  style="color:#888"size=0>
    <OPTION style="color:#888" selected> Issue Type </option>
    <OPTION style="color:#888" value="Hotel"> Hotel </option>
    <OPTION style="color:#888" value="Flights"> Flights </option>
</SELECT>
```

**SCRIPT :**

```
var tree = {
    "Hotel": [{val: "Htl1", text: 'Cancel'},
        {val: "Htl2", text: 'Modify'},
        {val: "Htl3", text: 'Research'},
        {val: "Htl4", text: 'Complaint'}],
    "Flights": [{val: "Flt1", text: 'Void'},
        {val: "Flt1", text: 'Cancel'},
        {val: "Flt1", text: 'Change Flight'},
        {val: "Flt1", text: 'Schedule Change'},
        {val: "Flt1", text: 'Name Change'}, ]
};



$(function() {

    $('#mainIssueType').change(function() {
        //get current selected option
        var selectVal = $('#mainIssueType :selected').val();
        //create a new select box and add to body
        var sel = $('<select>').appendTo('body');
        //give the new element an id matching 
        //the selected value from the previous element
        sel.attr('id', selectVal);
        //set the select box's options using the values 
        //from the "selectVal" object within the "tree" object
        $(tree.selectVal).each(function() {
            //tree.selectVal seems to be the problem
            sel.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.val).text(this.text));
        });
    });
});
```

The `tree.selectVal` in `$(tree.selectVal).each` seems to be the problem here. I guess this is not the same as saying `tree.Hotel` directly as I can get it to work using `tree.Hotel` as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rB7ZN/)

How can I access the object in `tree` whose name matches my `selectVal` variable?

Comment: tree["Hotel"], e.g., use tree notation. Tree[selectVal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `$(tree[selectVal])` instead of `$(tree.selectVal)`

```
$(function(){

   $('#mainIssueType').change(function() {
        //get current selected option
        var selectVal = $('#mainIssueType :selected').val(); 
        //create a new select box and add to body
        var sel = $('<select>').appendTo('body');
        //give the new element an id matching 
        //the selected value from the previous element
        sel.attr('id',selectVal);
        //set the select box's options using the values 
        //from the "selectVal" object within the "tree" object
        $(tree[selectVal]).each(function() {
            //_____^_____________________
            //tree.selectVal seems to be the problem
            sel.append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
        }); 
    });

});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/Rk7j9/1/)